# How can I wait until a web server is ready before launching a script

Tags: bash, grep, curl

I've gotten close to this working but I can't seem to get the script to end once successful.  It simply repeats.

For testing purposes, I'm just looking to display a dialog when the URL contains the string "RUNNING".  Eventually this will be my trigger to launch the client that requires the server to be ready.

In order to see what's happening I've added additional dialogs displaying the value of the $check.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
check="false"
webserv="http://localhost:8088/main/system/gwinfo"
Keyword="RUNNING" # enter the keyword for test content
zenity --error --text=$check --title="Warning\!";

until [$check=="true"]
do

zenity --error --text=$check --title="Warning\!"; 

if curl -s "$webserv" | grep "$Keyword";
then
    # if the keyword is in the conent
    zenity --error --text="RUNNING\!" --title="Warning\!"; 
    check="true";

fi
done
```

What I see when I execute are the following dialogs:
1. false
2. false
3. RUNNING/!
4. true

After that it simply repeats RUNNING/! & true.  The until loop isn't seeing the true.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess problem is the `let check=true` .. as far as I remember this `let` only counds for inside the block meaning until the `fi` is reached... put only `check=true` and it should work. Alternatively you could have a look at `nc` it at least can show if a certain port is reached and connectable on a server like `nc localhost 8088`

Comment: I made the change. No difference. I then tried changing the initial declaration line:
check="true"

I would have thought it wouldn't even enter into the until but I still got the dialog box. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: It also has to be `$check=="true"`

Answer (score 0):

I figured since I could see that the variable wasn't being read outside the loop I needed to rethink it.  The entire purpose of the loop of course was to keep trying until the server was up. So I simplified the whole thing and just exited in the last step if true.

```
#!/bin/bash
check="false"
webserv="http://localhost:8088/main/system/gwinfo"
Keyword="RUNNING" # enter the keyword for test content

until [$check=="true"]
do



if curl -s "$webserv" | grep "$Keyword";
then
    # if the keyword is in the conent
    ./clientlauncher.sh scope=C project=Edge windowmode=fullscreen  
    exit

fi
done
```